# How to avoid sensitive information in POSTs from appearing in logs and debug emails?

Tags: django, security

One of my websites has a form for customers to submit their credit card information.

Under normal operation the sensitive information (credit card number, expiration date, etc) is fairly secured due to the SSL of the connection and the fact that the data may not be saved on the backend after the charging attempt.

The problem starts whenever an exception is raised by the backend code handling the request, since the exception details (which with Django include the POST QueryDict) contain the sensitive info in plain text. These in turn find their way into both the error logs and into emails which are sent to the admins.

Is there some elegant way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

You should read the docs at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-sensitive-information

There's support for filtering out sensitive information since Django 1.2.6, respectively 1.3.1, and sensitive data in 'django.contrib.auth.views' is filtered out by default since Django 1.4.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of one off the top of my head, but it would be fairly straight forward to write a bit of middleware that replaces the values with `unicode`-like values which can't be `repr`'d. For example:

```
class sensitive_unicode(unicode):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<sensitive_unicode>"

class SensitiveDataHidingMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        for key, val in request.POST.iteritems():
            if key.startswith("sensitive_"):
                request.POST[key] = sensitive_unicode(val)
```

(actually, it might not be quite that simple because I think `request.POST` is immutable… So you'd have to force it to be mutable or copy it or something, but that's the general idea).